# Creating dropdown like Django Admin

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I hope you're all fine.

Thats my first ask here.

I am trying to build a dropdown like this:
[admin button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2spr.png)

What i have is:[my button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWTz4.png)

Participant is a model, so it haves some fields like name and institution.

How can i add a button like this to my django app, with the add/edit/remove? (I don't want to do this on Admin, but in the app)

Thats my forms.py: [forms.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXIKd.png)

These are my models: [session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlD9V.png) and [participant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPTRG.png)

Instead of 'participant' and 'session_name' i want to add something like the first image to 'participant' and 'session' models.

Comment: Are you familiar with django forms?

Comment: I did a form, but all fields are just text. I have a field to "participant" but it's just a TextField, so i can type only the name. What i want is a button like the image

Comment: Can you share the form and your models? You should use a `ModelChoiceField` to have a drop down populated with rows from a model

Comment: Thank you very much! i never saw that ModelChoiceField befofe. I will search about it.

Comment: I did it, but it still haven't the add, edit and remove icons.. How can i do  that?

Comment: You would have to implement that in your template, do you have views to perform those actions?

Comment: I thought django had already that implemented just like the admin page. So, i need to implement these add/change/remove options on views.py, right?

Comment: Django uses the admin pages for those actions. If you don't want to use the admin, yes, you'll need to implement them yourself.